# IIS forward web pages from multiple web servers on a private ip to a public site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iot

I have an IoT setup with hundreds of units connecting to my central server via a VPN using a private IP address space. Each runs a web server and from my central windows server machine I display the pages from (say) http://10.1.2.253 
I am looking for the best way to make those pages available via the internet. Using c# and asp .net but can expand my horizons.

Comment: Pure networking related questions are not covered here.

Comment: sorry, didn't think it was pure networking. I have tried iframes or just loading the response as html into a div, but would prefer it to be a direct connect.

Comment: In my opinion, you should have a public IP address firstly. Then you could use arr reverse proxy to forward the request to the backend server. If you have multiple web servers, you could also modify the genrated url rewrite rule to create speical rule(with speical path in the url) to each differernt server. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: Thank you Brando - we have the public IP address and are already running other sites so i will have a good read of the article you mentioned.